# Are there alternatives to gdi32 and ole32 under Linux?

Tags: linux, go, cgo

I want to use some methods in the ole32 and gdi32 libraries under Linux, but these two libraries do not exist under Linux, so are there alternatives when using under Linux?

I am using CGO

Use the following way to quote

```
#cgo LDFLAGS: -lws2_32 -lgdi32 -lole32
```

Comment: Linux has its own graphics stack, so asking for alternatives does not make much sense, and you should tell us what exactly you want to do, so people can tell you which exact library to use.

Comment: well, `ws2_32` appears to be Winsock; Go has excellent support for TCP/IP directly. But GDI and OLE are proprietary Windows stuff with no direct 1-to-1 support form anything on non-Windows platforms. The GUI part can be covered by cross-platform alternatives, but OLE cannot: mostly because in isolation, OLE is not interesting, and you're most probably using other pieces of software or COM-enabled libraries via the OLE layer. I mean, your problem is more deep than not having certain libs on non-Windows platforms.

Answer (score 0):

No, there are no in-place alternatives for these libraries on Linux as they are part of proprietary Win32 API and facilities they provide are specific to Windows only.

To make your application build on Windows and Linux you will need to abstract parts of application that use Windows specific libraries and implement them again for Linux using relevant replacement libraries (likely with different interface). Typically this is done so that programming interface - such as functions, methods, types, etc. towards your application are same but the underlying implementation is platform specific (using e.g. gdi32 on Windows and your favorite GUI framework on Linux). To achieve this Go provides [Build Constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) mechanism that tells compiler to pull-in/ignore only certain files from codebase on each platform.

Go's own [os](https://github.com/golang/go/tree/master/src/os) package is good example of doing this.

If your application is heavily dependent on Windows ecosystem and porting does not make sense, perhaps building Windows native binary and running it in Wine emulation layer on Linux might be cost-efficient option.